# How to include multiple components and then potentially call a function from one to the other?

Tags: javascript, angular

So I'm still quite new to AngularJS 2 and have a few questions that I have been unable to find clear answers to online.

My first question is how does one include multiple components in your angular2 app? This is how I'm currently doing it but I believe I'm doing it WRONG. Furthermore, can you look at how I'm including a service?

bootstrap.ts

```
// DEPENDENCIES GO HERE

bootstrap(App,[
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

app.ts

```
// DEPENDENCIES GO HERE

import {Socket} from './services/socket.ts'; // Socket.io Service
import {Second} from './pages/secondComponent.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-component'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: '/views/template.html',
  directives: [Second]
})
@RouteConfig([
  new Route({path: '/', component: Home, as: 'Home'}),
  new Route({path: '/home', component: Home, as: 'Home'})
])
export class App {
  router: Router;
  location: Location;
  socket: Socket;

  constructor(router: Router, location: Location) {
    this.router = router;
    this.location = location;
    this.socket = new Socket(); // <-- Is this how to use a "service"? I'm sure this is wrong as I would need to create a new socket instance every time I wanted to use it? Singleton?
  }
}
```

secondComponent.ts

```
// DEPENDENCIES GO HERE

@Component({
  selector: 'second-component'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: '/views/second.html'
})
export class Second {
  constructor() {

  }
  public callme() {
      return "I work!";
  }

}
```

If I include the second Component as a directive inside of the @view in the app.ts file it loads but I believe this is wrong as it's a component and not a directive.

Lastly, how would I go about calling the "callme()" function in the secondComponent.ts file FROM the app.ts file?

```
var second = new Second(); 
second.callme()
```

works but not sure if this is right because I think it's instantiating the component again??

I appreciate your help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question is how does one include multiple components in your angular2 app?

```js
// Note that @View is optional
// see https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4566
@Component({
    directives : [Cmp1, Cmp2, Cmp3, Cmp4, CmpN] 
})

// Or
@Component({})
@View({
    directives : [Cmp1, Cmp2, Cmp3, Cmp4, CmpN] 
})
```

Regarding on how to inject `Services`. It's much simpler than that (angular2 creates the instance for you, there's no need for `new` ;) )

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'main-component',
  providers : [Socket] // <-- Inject it into the component
})
export class App {
  socket: Socket;

  constructor(socketSvc: Socket) { // <-- Get the instance created above
    this.socket = socketSvc;
  }
}
```

You can see an example of it under [`viewProviders`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html).

> If I include the second Component as a directive inside of the @view in the app.ts file it loads but I believe this is wrong as it's a component and not a directive.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with including your components through `directives` property, in fact that's how you do it, also [Components extends from Directives](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L823).

> Lastly, how would I go about calling the "callme()" function in the secondComponent.ts file FROM the app.ts file?

You just query for App's children

```js
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  // Assuming you have only one 'Second' child, if you have multiple you must use @ViewChildren
  @ViewChild(Second) second: QueryList<Second>;

  afterViewInit() {
    this.second.callMe();
  }
}
```

I'd recommend you to go through the [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), you are missing some basic steps mentioned on it.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me! I will definitely have at the tutorial you linked. Cheers again.